# Ads Not working in Device but working in Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, ads

In my app, I am displaying Ads using Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.AdControl. The ads have already been working in the emulator for a few days but it has not been working on my development Windows Phone.

I'm not sure what's going because the code is exactly the same. But the result is different for emulator and device. I have tested in 7.1 version of the Windows Phone physical device and 7.0 of the emulator

If anyone knows how to fix this please share your ideas.

Comment: I think have the same issue, except I get only Microsoft Advertising Ads offering $50 of free ads on Bing

Comment: What version of the AdControl are you using?  i.e. the MS Ad SDK?

Comment: If someone stumbles over this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429319/adcontrol-dissapears-after-split-second-wp7 helped a lot for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue in the past. There are a few possible solutions.

- Check to make sure you are not running in debug mode (in the code not actual debuging in VS)
- Clean solution and rebuild (When you do UI changes many times you need a clean build)
- Ensure that the Reference Numbers are correct in your XAML properties
- Make sure that both the Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile and Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI are referenced
- Finally make sure that the device is disconnected from your computer when running

I know this is a lot of things to check however this sounds more like a file hasn't been updated properly issue then a miss set setting issue. Your best bet is to delete the ad control. Clean solution, Build solution. Create new ad control, clean solution, build solution. Delete app from device. Plug device in and build to device.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the phone has no internet connectivity?