# adcontrol dissapears after split second - WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, controls, ads

I've been struggling with this for weeks now, and can't figure out why it doesn't work.
I'm beta testing my first app WP7 app and want to fund it by ad-banners.
But all I see is a black square for a fractions of a second befor it turns invisible.
The beta version of the app can be downloaded here:
http://www.windowsphone.com/de-de/store/app/flyingfatty/196a2541-5989-48cd-8d0f-eacf988b47d7

To include the banners I took the following steps:

1. download the Windows Phone Ad SDK (WPAdSDK-DEU.msi)
2. add the Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile and Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI Refernce to my project.
3. add:   xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;assembly=Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI" to my xaml
4. add a 80x480 AdControl Element to my xaml
5. make a pub center account and register my app and the adcontrol.
   As categories I chose sports, travelling and shopping assuming, there's most ads in those categories
6. paste the applications-ID and adunit-ID to my xaml like below

`<my:AdControl AdUnitId="93769"`
    `ApplicationId="32b430d7-aa81-440d-99a1-62c65e75f64a"`
    `IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True"`
    `Height="80"`
    `HorizontalAlignment="Left"`
    `Margin="0"`
    `Name="adControlReal"`
    `VerticalAlignment="Bottom"`
    `Width="480" />`

As mentioned above I see a black banner for a split-second before it dissapears.
I also tried AdUnitId="Image480_800" and ApplicationId="test_client" for testing purposes but for the same effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try to subscribe to the error event to see why this is happening.

[AdControl.ErroOccurrred Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-adcontrol-silverlight-erroroccurred-event%28v=msads.20%29)

Comment: Andras. That was helpful. I subscribed to the error occured event and got: "this version of the ad control is not compatible with 7.0 apps." It seems, all I have to do is download another version of the Ad-SDK (hopefully). I thought I had the latest verion since I downloaded it from the Microsoft site recently. Many thanks

Comment: You should no longer target 7.0 apps. Only phones with mango update can download apps from the marketplace. Use and target the 7.1 sdk.

Comment: It took me a while, to realize, that is says 7.0. I started coding for windows phone only 4 month ago. Long after the 7.1 SDK came out. I have to investigate why apparently I'm using an outdated SDK. I was absolutely sure I downloaded the 7.1 version back then. Thanks again

Comment: Great it seems to work now. To sum it up: Apparantly I used the 7.0 SDk. All I had to do is download the latest SDK and change the version property of my project. The AdControl.ErrorOccurred Event was very useful to have a deeper look at whats going on. e.Error.Message returns a string in that event, which im my was a pretty specific. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same, my theory is the ads will display oftenly when the App has lots of downloads, the more popular the more ads and prints will have, if its a new App then it will show very few times, I say this because my App has 240+ downloads and the prints have been 250+ for which I have won $0.50 :) so it looks like if you see the square everything is fine

Comment: Jorge, thanks. that doesn't sound very encouraging - the $0.50 part I mean. When no ad is displayed do you see a black square instead? because in my case the square is black for a very short time and then turn completely invisible. Many thanks

Comment: Yeah I know :( anyway yes I see the black square with white border then dissapears, only once I could see an ad there, I don't open the App very often though, but I believe there are some prints of ads